# Собрать Qt -opensource на Ubuntu или Debian

Tags: qt, ubuntu, debian, configure

Нужно собрать Qt 5.12.2 на современном Ubuntu или Debian **с параметром -qt-xcb**. 
На Ubuntu 18.4.2 LTS и на Debian упираюсь в одну и ту же проблему. При выполнении confiigure получаю такую ошибку:

```
ERROR: Feature 'xcb' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'features.thread && features.xkbcommon && libs.xcb' failed.
```

При этом, до вызова confiigure, устанавливаю все пакеты, указанные здесь: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-requirements.html:

```
libfontconfig1-dev
libfreetype6-dev
libx11-dev
libxext-dev
libxfixes-dev
libxi-dev
libxrender-dev
libxcb1-dev
libx11-xcb-dev
libxcb-glx0-dev
```

Configure вызываю так:

```
unset QTDIR
export PATH="$PWD/qtbase/bin:$PWD/qtrepotools/bin:$PATH"
./configure \
    -release \
    -opensource \
    -confirm-license \
    -nomake examples \
    -nomake tests \
    -qt-libpng \
    -qt-libjpeg \
    -qt-zlib \
    -qt-xcb \
    -skip qtwebview \
    -skip qtwayland \
    -skip webchannel \
    -no-qml-debug \
    -prefix $PWD/qtbase \
    -prefix /home/user/qtbuild/res
```

Полный листинг вывода configure:

```
+ cd qtbase
+ /home/user/qt5122_build/sources/qtbase/configure -top-level -release -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-zlib -qt-xcb -skip qtwebview -skip qtwayland -skip webchannel -no-qml-debug -prefix /home/user/qt5122_build/sources/qtbase -prefix /home/user/qtbuild/res
Creating qmake...
.Done.

This is the Qt Open Source Edition.

You have already accepted the terms of the Open Source license.

Running configuration tests...
Done running configuration tests.

Configure summary:

Build type: linux-g++ (x86_64, CPU features: mmx sse sse2)
Compiler: gcc 7.3.0
Configuration: use_gold_linker sse2 aesni sse3 ssse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 avx avx2 avx512f avx512bw avx512cd avx512dq avx512er avx512ifma avx512pf avx512vbmi avx512vl compile_examples enable_new_dtags f16c largefile precompile_header rdrnd shani x86SimdAlways shared rpath release c++11 c++14 c++1z concurrent dbus reduce_exports reduce_relocations stl
Build options:
  Mode ................................... release
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Building shared libraries .............. yes
  Using C standard ....................... C11
  Using C++ standard ..................... C++1z
  Using ccache ........................... no
  Using gold linker ...................... yes
  Using new DTAGS ........................ yes
  Using precompiled headers .............. yes
  Using LTCG ............................. no
  Target compiler supports:
    SSE .................................. SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2
    AVX .................................. AVX AVX2
    AVX512 ............................... F ER CD PF DQ BW VL IFMA VBMI
    Other x86 ............................ AES F16C RDRAND SHA
    Intrinsics without -mXXX option ...... yes
  Build parts ............................ libs tools
Qt modules and options:
  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... no
  Qt Gui ................................. yes
  Qt Network ............................. yes
  Qt Sql ................................. yes
  Qt Testlib ............................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............................. yes
  Qt Xml ................................. yes
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... yes
  udev ................................... no
  Using system zlib ...................... no
Qt Core:
  DoubleConversion ....................... yes
    Using system DoubleConversion ........ no
  GLib ................................... yes
  iconv .................................. no
  ICU .................................... yes
  Tracing backend ........................ <none>
  Logging backends:
    journald ............................. no
    syslog ............................... no
    slog2 ................................ no
  Using system PCRE2 ..................... no
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... yes
  IPv6 ifname ............................ yes
  libproxy ............................... no
  Linux AF_NETLINK ....................... yes
  OpenSSL ................................ no
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ no
  DTLS ................................... no
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
Qt Gui:
  Accessibility .......................... yes
  FreeType ............................... yes
    Using system FreeType ................ no
  HarfBuzz ............................... yes
    Using system HarfBuzz ................ yes
  Fontconfig ............................. no
  Image formats:
    GIF .................................. yes
    ICO .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. yes
      Using system libjpeg ............... no
    PNG .................................. yes
      Using system libpng ................ no
  EGL .................................... no
  OpenVG ................................. no
  OpenGL:
    Desktop OpenGL ....................... yes
    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ no
  Vulkan ................................. no
  Session Management ..................... yes
Features used by QPA backends:
  evdev .................................. yes
  libinput ............................... no
  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
  mtdev .................................. no
  tslib .................................. no
  xkbcommon .............................. no
  X11 specific:
    XLib ................................. yes
    XCB Xlib ............................. yes
    EGL on X11 ........................... no
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. no
  LinuxFB ................................ yes
  VNC .................................... yes
  Mir client ............................. no
Qt Sql:
  SQL item models ........................ yes
Qt Widgets:
  GTK+ ................................... no
  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows
Qt PrintSupport:
  CUPS ................................... no
Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... no
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite2 ................................ no
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
  TDS (Sybase) ........................... no
Qt Testlib:
  Tester for item models ................. yes
Qt SerialBus:
  Socket CAN ............................. yes
  Socket CAN FD .......................... yes
Qt QML:
  QML network support .................... yes
  QML debugging and profiling support .... no
  QML sequence object .................... yes
  QML list model ......................... yes
  QML XML http request ................... yes
  QML Locale ............................. yes
  QML delegate model ..................... yes
Qt Quick:
  Direct3D 12 ............................ no
  AnimatedImage item ..................... yes
  Canvas item ............................ yes
  Support for Qt Quick Designer .......... yes
  Flipable item .......................... yes
  GridView item .......................... yes
  ListView item .......................... yes
  TableView item ......................... yes
  Path support ........................... yes
  PathView item .......................... yes
  Positioner items ....................... yes
  Repeater item .......................... yes
  ShaderEffect item ...................... yes
  Sprite item ............................ yes
Qt Scxml:
  ECMAScript data model for QtScxml ...... yes
Qt Gamepad:
  SDL2 ................................... no
Qt 3D:
  Assimp ................................. yes
  System Assimp .......................... no
  Output Qt3D Job traces ................. no
  Output Qt3D GL traces .................. no
  Use SSE2 instructions .................. yes
  Use AVX2 instructions .................. no
  Aspects:
    Render aspect ........................ yes
    Input aspect ......................... yes
    Logic aspect ......................... yes
    Animation aspect ..................... yes
    Extras aspect ........................ yes
Qt 3D Renderers:
  OpenGL Renderer ........................ yes
Qt 3D GeometryLoaders:
  Autodesk FBX ........................... no
Qt Bluetooth:
  BlueZ .................................. no
  BlueZ Low Energy ....................... no
  Linux Crypto API ....................... no
  WinRT Bluetooth API (desktop & UWP) .... no
Qt Sensors:
  sensorfw ............................... no
Qt Quick Controls 2:
  Styles ................................. Default Fusion Imagine Material Universal
Qt Quick Templates 2:
  Hover support .......................... yes
  Multi-touch support .................... yes
Qt Positioning:
  Gypsy GPS Daemon ....................... no
  WinRT Geolocation API .................. no
Qt Location:
  Qt.labs.location experimental QML plugin . yes
  Geoservice plugins:
    OpenStreetMap ........................ yes
    HERE ................................. yes
    Esri ................................. yes
    Mapbox ............................... yes
    MapboxGL ............................. yes
    Itemsoverlay ......................... yes
QtXmlPatterns:
  XML schema support ..................... yes
Qt Multimedia:
  ALSA ................................... no
  GStreamer 1.0 .......................... no
  GStreamer 0.10 ......................... no
  Video for Linux ........................ yes
  OpenAL ................................. no
  PulseAudio ............................. no
  Resource Policy (libresourceqt5) ....... no
  Windows Audio Services ................. no
  DirectShow ............................. no
  Windows Media Foundation ............... no
Qt Tools:
  QDoc ................................... no
Qt WebEngine:
  Embedded build ......................... no
  Pepper Plugins ......................... yes
  Printing and PDF ....................... yes
  Proprietary Codecs ..................... no
  Spellchecker ........................... yes
  Native Spellchecker .................... no
  WebRTC ................................. yes
  Use System Ninja ....................... no
  Geolocation ............................ yes
  WebChannel support ..................... no
  Use v8 snapshot ........................ yes
  Kerberos Authentication ................ no
  Use ALSA ............................... no
  Use PulseAudio ......................... no
  Optional system libraries used:
    re2 .................................. no
    icu .................................. no
    libwebp, libwebpmux and libwebpdemux . no
    opus ................................. no
    ffmpeg ............................... no
    libvpx ............................... no
    snappy ............................... no
    glib ................................. yes
    zlib ................................. no
    minizip .............................. no
    libevent ............................. no
    jsoncpp .............................. no
    protobuf ............................. no
    libxml2 and libxslt .................. yes
    lcms2 ................................ no
    png .................................. no
    JPEG ................................. no
    harfbuzz ............................. yes
    freetype ............................. no
    x11 .................................. yes
  Required system libraries:
    fontconfig ........................... no
    dbus ................................. no
    nss .................................. no
    khr .................................. yes
    glibc ................................ yes
  Required system libraries for qpa-xcb:
    libdrm ............................... yes
    xcomposite ........................... no
    xcursor .............................. no
    xi ................................... no
    xtst ................................. no

Note: Also available for Linux: linux-clang linux-icc

WARNING: QDoc will not be compiled, probably because libclang could not be located. This means that you cannot build the Qt documentation.

Either ensure that llvm-config is in your PATH environment variable, or set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR to the location of your llvm installation.
On Linux systems, you may be able to install libclang by installing the libclang-dev or libclang-devel package, depending on your distribution.
On macOS, you can use Homebrew's llvm package.
On Windows, you must set LLVM_INSTALL_DIR to the installation path.

ERROR: Feature 'xcb' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'features.thread && features.xkbcommon && libs.xcb' failed.

Check config.log for details.
```

При других подходах ставил ещё пачку либ, но на результат это не повлияло. Можно ли как-то понять, что именно не хватает для сборки?

Comment: «Check config.log for details.»

Answer (score 1):

В параметры configure добавлено

```
-feature-thread
-feature-xkbcommon
```

Установлена xkbcommon либа. Но Qt 5.12.2 configure выполнялась с ошибкой.

Удалось выполнить configure только для **Qt 5.13.0 beta2**.

Итоговая configure

```
unset QTDIR
export PATH="$PWD/qtbase/bin:$PWD/qtrepotools/bin:$PATH"
./configure \
    -release \
    -opensource \
    -confirm-license \
    -nomake examples \
    -nomake tests \
    -qt-libpng \
    -qt-libjpeg \
    -qt-zlib \
    -qt-xcb \
    -skip qtwebview \
    -skip qtwayland \
    -skip webchannel \
    -no-qml-debug \
    -prefix $PWD/qtbase \
    -prefix /home/user/qtbuild/res 
    -feature-thread \
    -feature-xkbcommon
```

Ссылки по теме:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/100908/qt-5-12-2-raspberry-pi-x11/18
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-74326